# Get an image source in selenium with chromedriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am working with selenium webdriver in C# and am attempting to get the src of an image using the GetProperty method to verify that the correct image is showing up.

```
var productImg = product.FindElement(By.TagName("img"));
var productSrc = productImg.GetProperty("src");
```

When run with firefox I get the image source as follows :

```
"https://s7d7.scene7.com/is/image/GTMSportswear/?fmt=png-alpha&amp;hei=184&amp;wid=184&amp;bgc=ffffff&amp;GTM_Group=1&amp;layer=0&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=Layer1&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone1$))&amp;$Zone1=Sub_Gold&amp;GTM_Group=2&amp;layer=1&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=GraphicBody&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;anchor=750,0&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone2$?src=is(GTMSportswear/U118TL-Century-1A)))&amp;$Zone2=Sub_White&amp;GTM_Group=3&amp;layer=2&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=GraphicBody&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;anchor=750,0&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone3$?src=is(GTMSportswear/U118TL-Century-1B)))&amp;$Zone3=Sub_Silver&amp;GTM_Group=4&amp;layer=3&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=GraphicBody&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;anchor=750,0&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone4$?src=is(GTMSportswear/U118TL-Century-1C)))&amp;$Zone4=Sub_Black&amp;GTM_Group=5&amp;layer=4&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=Binding&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone5$))&amp;$Zone5=Sub_White&amp;GTM_Group=6&amp;layer=5&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=Inside&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/Sub_Silver))"
```

Which is the correct image source.

When running this with firefox everything works as intended, though when I run this with chromedriver I get a null reference exception at GetProperty. When debugging productImg appears to be the exact same with both chromedriver and firefox driver. Googling and looking around on here I don't see anyone else with the same issue.

For refrence, the surrounding html:

```html
<div class="productCard">
    <figure>
      <img src="https://s7d7.scene7.com/is/image/GTMSportswear/?fmt=png-alpha&amp;hei=184&amp;wid=184&amp;bgc=ffffff&amp;GTM_Group=1&amp;layer=0&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=Layer1&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone1$))&amp;$Zone1=Sub_Gold&amp;GTM_Group=2&amp;layer=1&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=GraphicBody&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;anchor=750,0&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone2$?src=is(GTMSportswear/U118TL-Century-1A)))&amp;$Zone2=Sub_White&amp;GTM_Group=3&amp;layer=2&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=GraphicBody&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;anchor=750,0&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone3$?src=is(GTMSportswear/U118TL-Century-1B)))&amp;$Zone3=Sub_Silver&amp;GTM_Group=4&amp;layer=3&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=GraphicBody&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;anchor=750,0&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone4$?src=is(GTMSportswear/U118TL-Century-1C)))&amp;$Zone4=Sub_Black&amp;GTM_Group=5&amp;layer=4&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=Binding&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/$Zone5$))&amp;$Zone5=Sub_White&amp;GTM_Group=6&amp;layer=5&amp;resMode=sharp2&amp;src=ir(GTMSportswearRender/U118TL-Century?obj=Inside&amp;req=object&amp;decal&amp;show&amp;src=is(GTMSportswear/Sub_Silver))" alt="GTM Century UltraFuse SpiritFlex V-Neck Shell">
      <figcaption><b>GTM Century UltraFuse SpiritFlex V-Neck Shell</b></figcaption>
      <p class="productCard__options">
        Cuts: Women's, Girls<br>
        More Colors Available
      </p>
    </figure>

    <div class="productCard__pricing">
      <span class="productCard__pricing__price">$50.00</span>
      <br>
      <span>Price Includes Art</span>
      <br>
    </div>

    <div class="productCard__rating">
      <span class="icon star"></span><span class="icon star"></span><span class="icon star"></span><span class="icon star"></span><span class="icon star empty"></span>
      
    </div>

    <p class="productCard__banner"></p>
  </div>
```

Comment: try giving some wait

Comment: what's `GetProperty` method? Shouldn't it be `GetAttribute`? (I am not .NET user, but thought names are consistent between .NET and Java, and in Java it's definitely `getAttribute`)

Comment: I tried using the GetAttribute method and it returns an empty string every time with both firefox and chrome.

Comment: I just tried putting some delays in and got the same results.

Comment: Can you update the question with the result you see with `var productSrc = productImg.GetProperty("src");` when _running this with firefox_ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var productImg = dr.FindElement(By.TagName("img"));
var productSrc = productImg.GetAttribute("src");
```

Try the above code:

Comment: When using the GetAttribute I get an empty string back in both firefox and chrome.

Comment: Make sure how many image tag is available in the page which you are working. If that page has multiple image tag write the corresponding XPath for which image you actually want to verify. Like below :

   //div[@class='productCard']/figure/img[1]

Then try to get the attribute for that Xpath.